# How could i use css to make my Grid template fit to column

Tags: css, reactjs

This is my css code and this is how my images show up
This is my html code and it shows all of the  but theres also a Car component that has more code in it

```
   <section className="Carslist">
      <div className="Carslist-center">
        {cars.map(item => {
          return <Car key={item.id} car={item} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </section>








.Carslist {
  padding: 5rem 0;
}
.Carslist-center {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 776px) {
  .Carslist-center {
    width: 90vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .Carslist-center {
    width: 95vw;
    max-width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

[image]

I would like to make each picture fit fully to the grid

Comment: The grid items are aligned to the grid, but the issue is that the content within each item isn't expending to fill space/height. Can you share the CSS for the items displayed within each grid item? One option is to consistently size the car images though. You can also scale the images to fill a space but that can have adverse effects like stretching or cutting off parts of the image. Ideally you want all of the car to display. Please update question with how you style the grid items.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your HTML code, but this CSS code should work

```
img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```